# Values changing in tableview after performing search

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I'm getting correct data after loading the page as shown in this screen[image]

getting correct data even after performing search like this image
[image]

but after search is cancelled im getting  wrong data (label should be ph:+ and Fax:+ but its displaying both as Fax:+ like this[image]

with this code

```
@implementation Staffdir
@synthesize tableview,filteredContentList,searchBar1;
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    searchBar1.delegate = self;
         __block   StaffDirectoryModel*staffdirectorymodel;
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://dev.devobal.com/GetData.aspx?Query=select%20*%20from%20tb_RHP_Staff_Directory"];
    _staffdirarr=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSMutableURLRequest *req=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [[[NSURLSession sharedSession]dataTaskWithRequest:req completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        NSMutableArray *jsonarr=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];

        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // Update UI
            for(int i=0;i<jsonarr.count;i++){
                staffdirectorymodel=[[StaffDirectoryModel alloc]init];
                staffdirectorymodel.name =[[jsonarr objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"Name"];
                staffdirectorymodel.occupation=[[jsonarr objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"Job_Title"];

                staffdirectorymodel.phonelabel =[[jsonarr objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"Phone"];

                staffdirectorymodel.faxlabel =[[jsonarr objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"Fax_Number"];
                 staffdirectorymodel.department =[[jsonarr objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"Department"];
                [_staffdirarr addObject:staffdirectorymodel];
                staffdirectorymodel=nil;
            }
                       [tableview reloadData];

        });




    }]resume];
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
//-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
//    return 1;
//}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    if (isSearching) {
        return [searchResults count];
    }else{
        return _staffdirarr.count;
    }

}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *cellidentifer = @"cell";

    StaffDirectoryModel*staffdirectorymodel=[[StaffDirectoryModel alloc]init];
    Staffcustom *cell= [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellidentifer];

    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[Staffcustom alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellidentifer];
    }
    [cell.fxlabel setHidden:NO];
    [cell.faxnumlabel setHidden:NO];
    if (isSearching) {

          staffdirectorymodel=[searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


        cell.namelabel.text = staffdirectorymodel.name;
        cell.occupationlabel.text = staffdirectorymodel.occupation;

        NSString*tempph=staffdirectorymodel.phonelabel;
        NSString*tempfax=staffdirectorymodel.faxlabel;


        if(tempph.length!=0)
        {
            cell.phonelabel.text = staffdirectorymodel.phonelabel;
        }
        else{
            cell.phlabel.text=@"Fax: +";
            cell.phonelabel.text = staffdirectorymodel.faxlabel;
            [cell.fxlabel setHidden:YES];
            [cell.faxnumlabel setHidden:YES];

        }


        if(tempfax.length==0)
        {
            [cell.faxnumlabel setHidden:YES];
            [cell.fxlabel setHidden:YES];

        }

        if([tempph length]!=0 &&[tempfax length]!=0){
            cell.faxnumlabel.text = staffdirectorymodel.faxlabel;
        }



        cell.Depart.text = staffdirectorymodel.department;






    }
    else{

        staffdirectorymodel=[_staffdirarr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


        cell.namelabel.text = staffdirectorymodel.name;
    cell.occupationlabel.text = staffdirectorymodel.occupation;
        NSString*tempph=staffdirectorymodel.phonelabel;
        NSString*tempfax=staffdirectorymodel.faxlabel;
        if(tempph.length!=0)
        {
        cell.phonelabel.text = staffdirectorymodel.phonelabel;
        }
        else{
            cell.phlabel.text=@"Fax: +";
            cell.phonelabel.text = staffdirectorymodel.faxlabel;
            [cell.fxlabel setHidden:YES];
            [cell.faxnumlabel setHidden:YES];

        }

        if(tempfax.length==0)
        {
                [cell.faxnumlabel setHidden:YES];
                [cell.fxlabel setHidden:YES];

        }

        if([tempph length]!=0 &&[tempfax length]!=0){
    cell.faxnumlabel.text = staffdirectorymodel.faxlabel;
        }
    cell.Depart.text = staffdirectorymodel.department;

    }
     cell.namelabel.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    cell.occupationlabel.textColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:0.5 green:0.0 blue:1 alpha:1.0];

    UIView * additionalSeparator = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,cell.frame.size.height-1,cell.frame.size.width,0.1)];
    additionalSeparator.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    [cell addSubview:additionalSeparator];
        return cell;

}
//- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
//    isSearching = YES;
//}
-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar*)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString*)searchText
{
    //[filteredContentList removeAllObjects];

    if(searchText.length!=0){
        isSearching=YES;
        NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate
                                        predicateWithFormat:@"name contains[c] %@",
                                        searchText];

        searchResults=(NSMutableArray *)[_staffdirarr filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
        [tableview reloadData];
    }
    else{
        isSearching=NO;
        [tableview reloadData];
    }

    //
}
- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    isSearching=YES;
    [tableview reloadData];}

- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    isSearching=NO;
    [tableview reloadData];}
```

and 
staffdirectory model class

```
@interface StaffDirectoryModel : NSObject
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString*name;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString*occupation;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString*phlabel;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString*phonelabel;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString*fxlabel;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString*faxlabel;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString*department;
```

staffcustom.h

```
@interface Staffcustom : UITableViewCell
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *fxlabel;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *namelabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *occupationlabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *phlabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *faxlabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *phonelabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *faxnumlabel;
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UILabel *Depart;
@end
```

Comment: It is cell reusability issue.

Comment: Can u be more specific?.it is only changing at 3 rd row

Comment: can you show us your Staffcustom.m file ?

Comment: @Nishanth Please check response and your conditions and also try to filter out data from array and reload the data from same array with using new array it will be easier and this.

Comment: @kujey....Staffcustom.m is uitableviewcell subclass

Comment: Yes, thank you. I know what it is. If you indeed have a reusability issue it might be there.